# Add a PDF link in a .NET Core project

Tags: asp.net, pdf, iis-express, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to add a PDF file to my .net core 2.0 project, it runs using IIS Express on my localhost, I already add the pdf file to my project file, and it shows up in Solution Explorer, and I added the corresponding link in my .cshtml like this:

```
<a href=@Url.Content("~/CMT-RPT User Guide.pdf")>Link to guide if it does not show</a><br/>
```

But after I run it, it cannot show up in my website, what is the problem?
Here are the screen shot of my solution explorer and the website I clicked the link.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9fPC.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLKG3.png)

Answer (score 4):

By default, Asp.net core will render static content only from the `wwwroot` directory.

The `wwwroot` is a special directory to keep all the static assets ( your images/css/js/static files like your pdf etc).

So move your pdf file to the `wwwroot` directory and the link will work.

It is possible to specify another directory as the a directory to serve other static content. Let's say you have a directory called `MyPdfs` in the app root, you can explicitly add this directory as one of the StaticFile source. To do this, go to your Startup.cs and update the Configure method to have the below code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                                                           ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     // Your existing code goes here

     app.UseStaticFiles();

     // This will add "Libs" as another valid static content location
     app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
     {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
              Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyPdfs")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/pdfs")
     });
}
```

The `PhysicalFileProvider` class is defined in the `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders` namespace. So you should add a using statement to that in your `Startup.cs` class.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
```

Now you can have a link which has it's `href` attribute pointing to to `/pdfs/yourFileName.pdf`

You also need to remove the spaces in file name, replace it with `_` or `-`

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/pdfs/CMT-RPT_User_Guide.pdf.pdf")'>Link </a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shyju! Your answer is awsome!

Comment: @V.zhao You should select this as an answer, it's a great answer

Comment: Can you explain what the "@MyPdfs" is referencing? And you have PathString("/pdfs") and the comments right above says  // This will add "Libs" as another valid static content location.

For example, I need to do this for documents inside a "/Pages/docs" folder. I can't figure out the syntax.