# Adding a simple Href tag on Razor Page to download a .pdf file

Tags: href, razor-pages

This works in my C# .NET Web form. It is a simple link to a .pdf file and it either opens it or prompts for location to download it. I have about 8 of this links for various documents. This has been working for years.

```
<a href="/docs/evaluationprocedure.pdf">Evaluation Procedure for New and Renewal Courses</a>
```

But in my new .NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages application I am migrating the application to I can't figure out how to make this simple link. No matter how I make the link I get this error:

```
This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:xxxx/docs/evaluationprocedure.pdf
```

The pdf is in "Pages/docs/" folder.

I have tried:

```
<a href="evaluationprocedure.pdf">Evaluation Procedure for New and Renewal courses</a>
"./docs/evaluationprocedure.pdf"
"~/docs/evaluationprocedure.pdf"
"Pages/docs/evaluationprocedure.pdf"
"~Pages/docs/evaluationprocedure.pdf"
"../docs/evaluationprocedure.pdf"
```

I have searched pretty extensively and I seem to get mostly answers to the desire to stream a file or dynamically create the file at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

So, right before I went to bed I tried googling the answer again and found this link over on the right that had no accepted answers (it had a zero in the green area in front of the Title/Link.

But I looked and there was an answer with 3 votes but no checkbox! My problem was that only the wwwwroot folder allows static file downloads. But the answer showed how to add code to the configuration in Startup.cs to allow downloads from a new custom folder of one's choosing.

[Add a PDF link in a .NET Core project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227616/add-a-pdf-link-in-a-net-core-project)

So I got this link in the wwwroot folder to work:

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/evaluationprocedure.pdf")'>Evaluation Procedure for New and Renewal courses</a>
```

I just copied the file over to wwwroot for initial test.
Now to use the rest of the answer to allow my docs folder to hold static files.